# switching out link text on hover - transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Looking for a simple solution to replacing text on a link on :Hover. I want a slight transition (text comes up from underneath) and just replace regular if java is turned off.

HTML

```
<div class="bot-text">
  <a href="">Go here</a>
  <a href="">Or go here</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bot-text a  {
  font: 600 15px/20px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #383737;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #383737;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

This creates a text button with a border and padding. on hover I want the text to change to something else (will always be less text). I want the text to replace the current link text with a slide up from the bottom on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `:after` pseudo element

```css
.bot-text a  {
  font: 600 15px/20px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #383737;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #383737;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.bot-text a:hover {
  color:transparent;
}

.bot-text a:hover:after {
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  left:40%;
  color:blue !important;
  content:"abc";
  animation: slideup 1s ease-in 0s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slideup 1s ease-in 0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slideup 1s ease-in 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideup {
  from {
    top:50px;
  }
  to {
    top:25px;
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slideup {
  from {
    top:50px;
  }
  to {
    top:25px;
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideup {
  from {
    top:50px;
  }
  to {
    top:25px;
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bot-text">
  <a href="">Go here</a>
  <a href="">Or go here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3550879 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after#Browser_compatibility , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Browser_compatibility