# How can I slow down a text on hover?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make a button where a text appears before another text only on hover. I achieved that but can't put any delay on it.

See how fast the word "let's" appears. Need to slow that down.

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  width: 200px;
}

.btn:hover::before {
  content: "Let's ";
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
Go
</button>
```

I tried to use this answer [switching out link text on hover - transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555119/switching-out-link-text-on-hover-transition), but it is actually replacing the original text no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the text present initially and create a transition of width for example:

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  width: 200px;
}

.btn::before {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
  content: "Let's ";
  max-width:0px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:1s;
}
.btn:hover::before {
  max-width:50px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
Go
</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `transition-delay` with `opacity`

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  width: 200px;
}

.btn::before {
  opacity: 0;
  content: "Let's ";
  transition: all .3s linear 0s;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
}

.btn:hover::before {
  transition: all .5s linear .3s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by adding a delay to the transition?

```
.btn {
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
```